# firestore flutter recalculate all data stored if another data is updated

Tags: firebase, flutter

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fjecj.png)I have data stored in firebase as below

The planned Start and planned finish are calculated mathematically
planned finish = planned start +duration
planned Start = planned finish of dependent sl no
for sl no 10 dependent is 9 so planned Start of 10 is equal to planned finish of 9
So my problem is if I updated planned finish of sl no 9 then how can I make 10 to automatically update it planned start and finish
The code on how data is saved  is as below

```
 if (slno != null && activity != null) {
                      if (action == 'create') {
                        // Persist a new product to Firestore
                        Future<Timestamp> getslno() async {
                          var document =
                              await _schedule.doc(dependent.toString()).get();
                          Timestamp sl = await document['plannedfinish'];
                          return sl;
                        }

                        var planneds = await getslno();
                        await _schedule.doc(slno.toString()).set({
                          "slno": slno,
                          "activity": activity,
                          "duration": duration,
                          "dependent": dependent,
                          "plannedstart": planneds,
                          "plannedfinish": planneds
                              .toDate()
                              .add(Duration(days: duration!.toInt()))
                        });
                      }

                      if (action == 'update') {
                        // Update the product
                        await _schedule.doc(documentSnapshot!.id).update({
                          "slno": slno,
                          "activity": activity,
                          "duration": duration,
                          "dependent": dependent
                        });
                      }
```

I need all the data stored to be automatically updated if at least one data is changed
Any suggestions on how to do it

Answer (score 1):

Use firebase cloud functions, and utilized document `onUpdate`. Even if you don't know JavaScript, the functional logic is easy to implement in your equation, and the firebase admin SDK for firestore is similar to a large degree in what you are writing in Flutter.
That would be the ideal solution, otherwise, whenever someone updates a document, you need to use another function in your app to fetch the document and recalculate then update it again on the client side, which isn't very favored.
To enable cloud functions it asks for billing info, but you aren't billed until after two million api invocations. Would strongly recommend you drive into this and unleash the power.

Comment: Can you suggest me how can i proceed if i want to write a function in my app itself

Comment: The documentation for Firebase is probably one of the best written docs out there. Very clean, precise, has examples straight to the point, and escalates gradually. That would be my best suggestion. Read the docs, to see what possibilities you have, better than finding the exact code you are looking for, instead, it'll spark your mind to attempt perhaps other solutions you weren't thinking of.